# What genre is A Plague Tale: Requiem?

Tags: genre-identification, a-plague-tale-innocence, a-plague-tale-requiem

I am not a competitive gamer; when I play, I play for fun, playing casually and solving the puzzle that is the game.

I have played *A Plague Tale: Innocence* as well as *A Plague Tale: Requiem* for almost 2 years now. I keep going over and over in the game — the replay value for me is immense! I will probably do another play-through or two before I am really ready to move on, but please, I need some advice:

This is the EXACT type of game I like, and I am not really sure what "genre" it is. What I know that describes the games for me are:

- Third-person
- Using projectile weapons (but not a classic "shooter")
- Adventure
- Horror
- Thriller
- Immersive
- Survival
- Story-rich
- Stealth, aggressive, or opportunistic play to get different upgrades

What do I call this kind of game? I am looking for similar games to play.

In these games, the storyline doesn't change (except for some wording, but not endings or the direction the story evolves) depending on your actions, but I am not opposed to such games.

Comment: As an option for a somewhat similar game, try Signalis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a **narrative action-adventure** game, with touches of **stealth**.